# how to write model and store for this Json response from server in Sencha

Tags: model, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, store

This is my json response from server,

```
   {"class":"co.myapp.json.WsResponse","code":0,"message":"SUCCESS",
        "packet":
        {"class":"co.myapp.json.MyWantPacket","fullname":"Viswa","imageURI":"images/1.png","userid":1,"username":"viswa11","wantSuggestion":"learn guitar",
        "wants":[{
            "class" : "co.myapp.json.MyWant",
            "id" : 2,
            "replyCount" : 0,
            "text" : "Message 2",
            "time" : "Oct 3, 2012 - 14:59:02"
        }, {
            "class" : "co.myapp.json.MyWant",
            "id" : 1,
            "replyCount" : 2,
            "text" : "Message 1",
            "time" : "Oct 3, 2012 - 14:59:02"
        }]
    }}
```

I need fullname, imageuri, replayCount and text from above jsone,

*** This is my model**

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.Wants', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {

        fields : [
            { name : 'id', type : 'int'},
            { name : 'replyCount', type : 'int'},
            { name : 'text',type : 'string'},
                    { name : 'wants',type : 'string'},
                    { name : 'fullname',type : 'string'},
                    { name : 'imageURI',type : 'string'}
            { name : 'time', type : 'string',dateFormat : 'D'}
        ]
    }
});
```

*** This is my store**

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.WantsStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    config : {
        model : 'myApp.model.Wants',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
             url : http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/message/mwants?token=2143cede2ab147e6bc1cd5c7caa14792
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                rootProperty : 'packet'
            }
        },
        sorters : [{
            property : 'time',
            direction : 'DESC'
        }]
    }
});
```

***This is my DataViewList  (View)**

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.WantsList', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    xtype : 'wantslist',
    config : {
        itemCls : 'my-dataview-item',
        loadingText : 'Loading items...',
        emptyText : '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No Wants found.</div>',
        itemTpl : '<div><img src="{imageURI}"/><span class="list-item-title">{fullname}</span><span id="count" class="list-item-title">{replyCount}</span><p class="list-item-title">{text} <span id="time" class="list-item-title">{time}' 
        + '</span></p>'
    }
});
```

How do change model,store and view  ** so that i can display fullname, imageuri, replayCount and text in DataViewList.

### also i want to display list like

image fullname replayCount text time (this is 1 item in a list)

image fullname replayCount text time (this is 2 item in a list)

image fullname replayCount text time (this is 3 item in a list)

image fullname replayCount text time (this is 4 item in a list)

........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have correctly configured your clasess, but your packet property in the JSon must be an array, if not you can only have a single Record in your Store. I mean:

```
{"class": "co.myapp.json.WsResponse",
  "code":0,
  "message":"SUCCESS",
  "packet": [{
      "class":"co.myapp.json.MyWantPacket",
      "fullname":"Viswa",
      "imageURI":"images/1.png",
...
```

See the [ at the beginning of the packet object.

Comment: my problem is i can't change json coming from server